# Why is my if statement ignoring the Boolean "true" value condition?

Tags: javascript, html

The lines of code I wrote are based on the principle that because the presence of an object or array can be considered truthy, it's often used to check for the existence of an element within a page. But I'm guessing my condition fall into neither of this category. The code works when I put (el.className === "green") as a condition though.

```js
var el = document.querySelector("ul");
if(el.hasAttribute('green')){
  console.log("yes")
} else {
  console.log("no")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Practise App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <ul class="green">
    <li>Monday</li>
    <li>Tuesday</li>
  </ul>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The attribute is `class` not `green`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList You want to use contains

Answer (score 4):

`hasAttribute` means "Has an attribute with this name"

You said `class="green"`. It has a `class` attribute, not a `green` attribute (and can't have a `green` attribute in valid HTML).

It does not mean "Has an attribute, of *any* name, with this value". DOM doesn't have a function that does that. You'd need to loop over each attribute (e.g. via [the `attributes` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes)) and test each one in turn.

Comment: Thank you all. I changed my condition to (el.hasAttribute("class")). My if statement is now behaving as it should be.